# Se deben de agregar las activities y fragmentos en un diagrama de clases?

Tags: java, android, uml

Tengo que hacer un poco de ingeniería inversa y realizar un diagrama de clases de un aplicación para android ya hecha, pero en realidad no sé si deba de agregar las actividades y fragmentos de la app o pueden ir en otro diagrama.

Comment: Revisa esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y realizael [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos.

Comment: cuando hablamos de un diagrama debes especificar primero cual de tantos diagramas piensas hacer, por ejemplo, si vas a hacer un diagrama de clases entonces debes estar reflejando las entidades o clases que hacen parte del model o data de la aplicación más no de la vista. Por ejemplo una aplicación de una biblioteca tendría las clases usuario, empleado, libro, seccion, autor etc.

Comment: Si es una aplicación Android es importante que agregues las Activities, los Fragments dentro de las Activities y la relación entre métodos. Me parece que tu pregunta depende de la cantidad de relaciones si te recomiendo usar el plugin Code Iris para android studio. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MtCQYIiyd8g

Comment: Si es clase, va en el diagrama de clases de UML. Si no es clase, no va como parte del diagrama de clases. Por ejemplo, si diagramas las clases de una aplicación web, los archivos JSP y otros de vista, como no son clases, no van en el diagrama. Existen otros diagramas donde esta información se visualiza.

Answer (score 0):

Todo depende de lo que quieras documentar. Los diagramas de clases son muy dependientes del contexto que quieras clarificar al programador. Yo en mi caso no incluyo los activities en los diagramas de clases, me centro en las clases funcionales y dejo los activities como parte de la capa de presentación.